# Internal Server Error for User.objects.get(email=email)

Tags: django

I want to check if a given email exists in auth_user of django

First I import

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

In the controller, I test like this:

```
user_by_email = User.objects.get(email=email) # internal server error at this point.
if user_by_email is not None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

But this line returns internal server error.

Than I created a new row in auth_user manually, it worked as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `filter`

```py
user_by_email = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
if not user_by_email:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Comment: Thank you. We wrote in the same moment but I will select this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer:

When you use filter, it doesn't cause internal server error:

```
user_by_username = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
if user_by_username is not None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```